# How do I scale a rigged character without making it move randomly?

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms

I've been trying to scale a rigged character. I applied a new animation to it from Mixamo which works well, but I am unable to scale it. I've literally been trying to scale a character up for two hours but every time I do, it goes back to being small. I've done Ctrl + A > Apply Scale but then it just causes my character to roam around randomly in space. I'm selecting the armature for scaling. Does anyone know a workaround for this? I've also uploaded a video to demonstrate what is going wrong.

[Please see the video here](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ha93b5/unable_to_scale_rigged_character_more_in_comments/)

Comment: it looks like we need to log in to see your video, maybe share your character (armature only) here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've uploaded the video [here](https://youtu.be/K5r9jIPuWE0) and a zip containing the armature [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oY-5yhSq0c3QUiBHvQPXloUnJBJ-6yt5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
The bones probably had a scale component on them, so they reset each time you hit play.
What I did was parent it to an empty then scale the empty instead.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that, at frame 1, you've keyframed the armature *Scale*, with a value of 0.01.

If you apply the *Scale* it means that you assign your armature its current size as its 1/1/1 scale. But as it continues to play the action's scale keyframes, it's immediately going to be scaled down to 0.01 of this new scale.

So what you can do is either apply its *Visual Transformation*, or delete the *XYZ* scale keyframes in the *Dope Sheet*.

Comment: i tried this with my mixamo important character, applied to armature + character, filtered in dope sheet by scale, deleted all keyframes, but still the animation is wrecked. What can it be?

Comment: hello Chris, maybe share your file?

Comment: i did on a new question ;)

Comment: does josh sanfelici he answer correctly? I haven't looked into your file yet...

Comment: I hadn’t the time to check that out…but as I know him…I think yes, it should be right. Was running and have to calm down my heartbeat…